# how to change image resolution of an html image in jsf

Tags: java, html, css, jsf

i have a jsf page which displays an image from an url [http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=^NSEI&t=1d&q=l&l=on&z=l&p=s&a=v&p=s](http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=%5ENSEI&t=1d&q=l&l=on&z=l&p=s&a=v&p=s)
i wish to make this image smaller than its original size, but when i do so, it gets distorted, it is not displayed as clear as the original one. below is the code:

xhtml:

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{equityBean.niftyUrl}" height="200" width="200"/>
```

bean code:

```
public String getNiftyUrl() {
    return "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=^NSEI&t=1d&q=l&l=on&z=l&p=s&a=v&p=s";
}
```

i guess when i make the image smaller, its resolution changes, how do i make it smaller keeping the same resolution?

Comment: Do you mean you want the image to be cropped rather than resized?

Comment: no i dont want it to be cropped, i want to display the whole image as it is by resizing it and keeping the same resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

none of the solutions worked. i used a different url instead- http://ichart.yahoo.com/t?s=^BSESN with its width and height as 190 and 95 respectively. it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to indicate only width. If want to indicate and height, you need to constrain image proportions. For your example: `width="200"` and `height="119"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is more on yahoo chart api. To reduce  image size while keeping the resolution change the `z=l` (large) to `z=m` (medium) or `z=s` (small)

`http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=^NSEI&t=1d&q=l&l=on&p=s&a=v&p=s&z=s`